# out_of_range try..catch block exception handling in c++

Tags: c++

`try..catch` blocks are not working. As I am a beginner in C++, please help me out with this piece of code. I am trying the same thing which is done [here](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stdexcept/out_of_range/), the only difference is that I am using a `std::map`.

```cpp
map<char, int> d; 
d.insert(pair<char, int>('a', 1));
try {
    cout << d['b'];
}
catch(const std::out_of_range){
    // perform some operations.
}
```

Comment: What does "is not working properly" mean?

Comment: You did not catch exception because it was not thrown. Why do you expect it to be thrown?

Comment: Is any exception thrown? The [] operator does not throw an exception for a map. Is it the call to at() that might fail?

Comment: "I just want the same thing in map" - there is no the same thing for `std::map`. `operator[]` of `std::map` works not how you expect it to work.

Comment: If you want to do the same thing with map, then you can do exactly that. `std::map` has an `at()` method that throws a `std::out_of_range`: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/at

Comment: Also, exception classes should be caught by reference, not by value

Answer (score 1):

For reference, this is the code that was linked in the question:

```cpp
// out_of_range example
#include <iostream>       // std::cerr
#include <stdexcept>      // std::out_of_range
#include <vector>         // std::vector

int main (void) {
  std::vector<int> myvector(10);
  try {
    myvector.at(20)=100;      // vector::at throws an out-of-range
  }
  catch (const std::out_of_range& oor) {
    std::cerr << "Out of Range error: " << oor.what() << '\n';
  }
  return 0;
}
```

If you want to do the same for a `::std::map`, it's as easy as swapping the `::std::vector` for a `::std::map`, since `::std::map` [also has an `at()` function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/at). That would look like this:

```cpp
// out_of_range example
#include <iostream>       // std::cerr
#include <stdexcept>      // std::out_of_range
#include <map>            // std::map
#include <utility>        // std::pair

int main (void) {
  std::map<int, int> mymap;
  try {
    mymap.at(20)=100;      // map::at throws an out-of-range
  }
  catch (const std::out_of_range& oor) {
    std::cerr << "Out of Range error: " << oor.what() << '\n';
  }
  return 0;
}
```